# DB Array to expected javascript format

Tags: php, javascript, arrays, charts, highcharts

I am implementing Highcharts in my application. It needs data in specific format.

The data in my table is as  follows

[image]

The javascript needs data in below format

[image]

When I `var_dump` my `x_axis` array and `y_axis` array, I get below result

[image]

Which php functions should I use to format my array elements and pass to that JavaScript in that format?

```
data:[
     [<? echo PHP_some_function(" ' ", x_axis) ?>, <? echo (y_axis) ?>]   //quotes for x, no quotes for y value
]  //Moreover it should run for all the values in x_axis and y_axis
```

I need some logic here..

My final graph would look like

[image]

Comment: you probably don't want to use those variables.  You probably want to extract your data as more complete record sets, each record containing x_axis, y_axis, and possibly si_no, ordered by y_axis descending.  Then it should be relatively straightforward

Comment: On the other side, that's one of the well asked questions I've seen recently!

Comment: This looks a lot like homework. Even the values are the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13954081/highcharts-pie-chart-x-axies-values-are-not-displayed-while-trying-to-get-data-f

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The problem is your query.**

It should be like the following.

```
SELECT x_axis, y_axis FROM yourTableName;
```

This way you'll get exactly the format that `Highcharts` needs. You just have to insert it inside an array.

Answer (score 1):

```
[<? echo "'". json_encode($x_axis). "', " . json_encode($y_axis) ?>]
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/G5JAtXWu

Nix that I was confused.

What you want to do is this:

```
foreach($x_axis as $key=>$x) {
    echo "['" . $x . "', " . $y_axis[$key] . "]";
}
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/SKNk1VaX

To wrap it all up:

```
$d = array();
foreach($x_axis as $key=>$x) {
    $d[] = "['" . $x . "', " . $y_axis[$key] . "]";
}
echo json_encode($d);
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/KhofwXCi

Comment: This does not take into account the sort that was requested.

Comment: @ScottSauyet I see no sort.

Comment: Look at the order of the data requested in the chart configuration.  Clearly descending values.  I have no idea if that's actually important, though.

Comment: @ScottSauyet Its ok if there is no sort.

Comment: @StrataGeeksCEO: Ok, did you end up getting this working, with or without a sort?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming:

```
$x_axis = array('Safari', 'Opera', 'Firefox', 'IE', 'Chrome', 'Others');
$y_axis = array(10, 6, 40.5, 20, 10.6, 0.5);
```

This should work:

```
$data = array();
$length = count($x_axis);
for ($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++) {
    $data[] = array($x_axis[i], $y_axis[i]);
}
```

Comment: This does not take into account the sort that was requested.

Comment: @ScottSauyet: OP did not request the data to be sorted, and I wouldn't be surprised if that graph's library took care of that

Comment: but look at the required data format, which has the data in a sorted order, one which does not match the input order.

Comment: _"@ScottSauyet Its ok if there is no sort. – StrataGeeks CEO 9 hours ago"_
- OP on another answer. Don't nitpick what doesn't need to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

probably array combine and than json encode and replace? just in case for diversity;)

```
<?php 

$x_axis = array(
'Safari', 'Opera', 'fireFox'
);

$y_axis = array(
10, 30.4, 50
);

$keyFilled = array_combine($x_axis, $y_axis);

arsort($keyFilled);

$jsonData = json_encode($keyFilled);

$jsonDataReplaced = str_replace(array(',', '{', '}', ':'), array('],[', '[', ']', ','), $jsonData);
echo '<pre>';
var_dump('['.$jsonDataReplaced.']');

?>
```

output is:

```
string(45) "[["fireFox",50],["Opera",30.4],["Safari",10]]"
```

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jq4-cgb

Comment: This does not take into account the sort that was requested.

Comment: @ScottSauyet, not really sure that it was requested, but it is easy to fix, updated